# Android: Calling a dialog from a button imbedded in a list

Tags: android, list, button, dialog

I have a custom List that contains two `TextViews` and two `Buttons`. I want one button to change the data shown in one `TextView` and I want the other `button` to inflate a `Dialog` explaining the purpose of that row. So I need to dynamically update the `Dialog` content. As far as I can tell the only way to imbued a clickable button in a list is to `setOnClickListener` in an adapter when you inflate the row, but I can't create a `dialog` outside of the `activity` (I'm getting a Force Close). Here's my `getView()` call. Any suggestions?

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_list_item,null);

        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.clear=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnClr);
        holder.label=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textListItemLabel);
        holder.value=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textListItemValue);
        holder.info=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnInfo);
        holder.group= (RadioGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        holder.r1=(RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        holder.r2=(RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        holder.t1=(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggle1);

        holder.clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            private int pos= position;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                holder.value.setText(String.valueOf(pos));
                notifyDataSetChanged();//I know there's a problem on here, and I'm working on that... but at least it reacts to the button press.

            }
        });

        holder.info.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            private int pos= position;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Button button = (Button) v;

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to display?");
                    .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                MyActivity.this.finish();
                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
                builder.create();//Ok to here...
                builder.show();//Crash
                String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Activity that containing the adapter can't handle it's own lifecycle  - `Activity.onPause()` when there is a request from a contained object such this adapter to cover the activity with Dialog.

So to handle it, move all the `AlertDialog` code to the activity inside a new method which will be called by pressing the button.

you can do that by fill the argument of the attribute `android:onClick`in the button xml's definition with the name of the method as mentioned before.

like here:
http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html